# Passing attributes as parameters and inserting into table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a database table called "User" with the following attributes:
UserId, Name, CreatedAt, CreatedBy, ModifiedAt, ModifiedBy, Address, City, Province, Country, PostCode, Phone.

What I need to do is create a class named as User Repository with a methode CreateUser. The method will take all attributes as parameter and will insert into tables respectively i.e. User

Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Comment: Are you having any problems with the code you currently have?

Comment: No i am a new bee. I am a bit confused. what i am doing is I created another class and got all the attributes as members. Now when i pass the object as a method's parameter it will take all attributes. How to insert it into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class with all your attributes

```
public class user {

public id UserId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string CreatedAt {get;set;}

public string createdBy {get;set;}
public string modifiedAt {get;set;}

public string modifiedBy {get;set;}
public string address {get;set;}

public string city {get;set;}
}
```

Create a repository - assuming you have UserDbContext.

```
// following method will insert new record into the database. 

    public void CreateUser(user data){
    _ctxmain = new UserDbContext();
    var newUser = new user {
    UserId = data.UserId,
    Name = data.Name,
    CreatedAt = data.CreatedAt,
    CreatedBy = data.CreatedBy,
    modifiedBy = data.modifiedBy,
    modifiedAt = data.modifiedAt,
    address = data.address,
    city = data.city

    };

    _ctxmain.User.Add(newUser);
    _ctxmain.SaveChanges();  // saving details to the User table in database

    }
```

Comment: Will this piece of code will produce the same result?                            
 public static void CreateUser(User user)
        {
            if (user == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            try
            {
                using (UserDbContext entities = new UserDbContext ())
                {
                    user.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    entities.Users.Add(user);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

Comment: Yes, it is the same code. You use entities instead of _ctxmain.